# Amending the user input from country code to country full name

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am trying to create a web page where the user enters a country name into the search box and it will display the selected information from the API and use leaflet maps to hone in on that country.

I'm still working through the code one step at a time, but at the moment I've managed to get the API information to display on my web page but the user input box will only accept country codes and not country names. I've tried everything I can find on it to help but things I have tried stop the API showing completely?

How can I resolve either of these issues? I'm a bit of a novice and still learning.

JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

// Creates a Leaflet Map and sets the initial view/starting point with coordiantes
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

//Adds the OpenStreetMap layer to the map and sets the max zoom level 
L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);

// Adds GeoJSON layer for country borders
var countryBordersLayer = L.geoJSON(null, {
    style: {
        color: 'black',
        weight: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0
    }
}).addTo(map);

// Load countryBorders.geo.json data and add it to the GeoJSON layer
$.getJSON('assets/countryBorders.geo.json', function(data) {
    countryBordersLayer.addData(data);
});

//Adds a marker with text in a popup
L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
    .openPopup();

//Adds a marker to the map at those coordinates
var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);

//Adds a circle to the map at those coordinates
var circle = L.circle([51.508, -0.11], {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    radius: 500
}).addTo(map);

// Will zoom into the users location once shared - geolocation
map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});

// Places a marker in the users location to show accuracy
function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy;

    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
        .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

    L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
}
// defines functions of whether the location of user was found or error if not
map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);

// Error message if the geolocation failed

function onLocationError(e) {
    alert(e.message);
}

map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

/* Uses geocoding service Nominatim API to search for a country - 
sets the map view to the countrys coordinates and calls a function to add points of interest */
function searchCountry() {
    var countryName = document.getElementById('country').value;

    // Use Nominatim API for geocoding
    var geocodingUrl = `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q=${encodeURIComponent(countryName)}`;

    fetch(geocodingUrl)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data && data.length > 0) {
                var boundingBox = data[0].boundingbox;
                var bounds = L.latLngBounds([boundingBox[0], boundingBox[2]], [boundingBox[1], boundingBox[3]]);

                // Fit the map to the country's bounding box
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            } else {
                alert('Country not found');
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}


// API Call 

//Sets up a click event handler for btnRun - when clicked the function is executed
$('#btnRun').click(function() {
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/countryInfo.php",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            country: $('#country').val(),
        },
        //callback function to handle a successful result
        success: function(result) {
                     
            console.log(result);

            var apiInformation = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2); 

            $('#countryInfoResults').text(apiInformation);

            if (result && result.status && result.status.name === "ok") {

                var countryInfo = countryInfo.geonames[0];

                $('#txtCapital').html(countryInfo.capital);
                $('#txtPopulation').html(countryInfo.population);
                $('#txtCurrency').html(countryInfo.currency);
                $('#txtLanguage').html(countryInfo.language);
                $('#txtCoordinates').html(countryInfo.coordinates);

                var coordinates = 'Latitude: ' + countryInfo.north + ', Longitude: ' + countryInfo.east;
                $('#txtCoordinates').html(coordinates);
                
                $('#countryInfoResults').show();
            } else {
                // Handle other cases, e.g., display an error message
                console.error("Error:", result.status.description);
                
            }

            // Assuming 'data' is the API response
            var apiInformation = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2); // Convert data to a formatted JSON string

            // Display the API information in the element with ID 'countryInfoResults'
            $('#countryInfoResults').text(apiInformation);


        }, //Callback function to handle the error in the AJAX reque
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error("AJAX Error:", textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
});
```

**countryBorders.geo.JSON.php:**

```
// This code parses the JSON data to create a mapping between country names and country codes
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");

// Read the GeoJSON file
$geoJsonData = file_get_contents("assets/countryBorders.geo.json");
$geoJsonArray = json_decode($geoJsonData, true);

// Extract country codes and names
$countries = array();
foreach ($geoJsonArray['features'] as $feature) {
    $properties = $feature['properties'];
    $country = array(
        'code' => $properties['ISO_A2'],
        'name' => $properties['ADMIN']
    );
    $countries[] = $country;
}

// Return the data as JSON
echo json_encode($countries);
```

**countryInfo.php:**

```php
<?php

/*Configure PHP to display errors - ini_set is used to set the configuration option. 
display_errors to on and error reporting is set to report all errors */
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* 1st line is a variable with a timestamp in microseconds - marking the start time of the script*/
$executionStartTime = microtime(true);

/* sets HTTP headers to allow cross-origin resource sharing & 
2nd specifies that the response will be in JSON format */
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json");

// Initialize an empty output array to store the data
$output = array();


/* Checks if 'lang' & 'country' parameters are provided - REQUEST is a superglobal that contains data 
from both 'GET' & 'POST' */
if (!isset($_REQUEST['country'])) {
    // Handle the case where the parameters are missing
    $output['status']['code'] = "400";
    $output['status']['name'] = "Bad Request";
    $output['status']['description'] = "Country parameter is missing";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
    $output['data'] = null;
} else {
    $url = 'http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?formatted=true&lang=en&country=' . $_REQUEST['country'] . '&username=susan.alexander&style=full';

       
    /* Initializes a cURL session ($ch) and sets various options such as 
    disabling SSL verification and setting the URL */
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    /* Executes the cURL session, stores the result and retrieves the HTTP code */
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    /* closes the cURL session */
    curl_close($ch);

    /* Handle the case where the API request is successful - if successful it decodes the JSON response
     - if not gives error code */
    if ($httpCode == 200) {
        // Assuming $result is a JSON string, decode it
        $apiData = json_decode($result, true);

        // Check if decoding was successful
        if ($apiData !== null) {
            $output['status']['code'] = "200";
            $output['status']['name'] = "OK";
            $output['status']['description'] = "Request successful";
            $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
            $output['data'] = $apiData;
        } else { /* constructs a JSON response indicating internal server error */
            $output['status']['code'] = "500";
            $output['status']['name'] = "Internal Server Error";
            $output['status']['description'] = "Error decoding API response";
            $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
            $output['data'] = null;
        }
    } else {
        // Handle the case where the API request failed
        $output['status']['code'] = $httpCode;
        $output['status']['name'] = "API Request Failed";
        $output['status']['description'] = "API request failed with HTTP code: $httpCode";
        $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
        $output['data'] = null;
    }
}

// Sends the JSON response
echo json_encode($output);
```

I've tried a few suggestions around amending my countryBorders.geo.json.php file but everything suggested then stops the API information showing at all, and I've tried amending the calls in JavaScript but again the ones suggested stop the API information coming through.

Comment: The `countryInfoJSON` endpoint only allows searching by country code. You'd have to check if any of the other endpoints accept the country _name_ as a search parameter instead; or you get the full list, and then search the entry with the matching country name in there yourself.